# Add Admob interstitial (full screen) ads to existing app with admob banner ads only

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I currently have apps with just banner ads. I would want to use interstitial ads also going forward. I was confused about the following:

- Can i use the same admod ad unit for both
- I'm not using mediation, will interstitial ads work ok without setting up mediation. meaning to say, will i get acceptable fill rates by just using admob for interstitial ads. Banners have worked fine so far with just admob. (no mediation)
- If it is mandatory to create another ad unit just for interstitial ads, is it possible to auto generate these for all of my apps? I have a few hundred apps and the thought of manually going about creating one manually for each.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can use the same AdUnit for both banner and mediation but doing so emans you have no way of differentiating between their revenue and eCPM.
2. I'm getting very good fill rates with Admob interstitials (95%+). Your mileage may vary.
3. Not mandatory to create another ad unit (as per 1). There is no way to auto generate ad units.

Comment: Thanks william. That's what i finally concluded after reading several blogs and forums. Btw, co-incidence, i think i happened to see a video of yours yesterday where you were being interviewed by an admob PR guy along with another guy called Kunal. It was about how you have implemented admob in your apps and all. I figured out it was you because somehow your name was taken several times by the interviewer and also you are sitting in the same place in your picture here as you were in that video. :)