# Add two Ad Unit in a single android application

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I wish to add Advertisement to my new application:

1) Banner Ad
2) Interstitial Ad

So for that i registered my new application in my admob account; and by using the Publisher ID of that application i am showing my banner ad unit.

Now where should i get my second Ad Unit Id for my interstitial ad.[How are interstitial ads and banner ads registered on the admob]

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the same adunit id for both banner and interstitial ads . Check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380208/add-admob-interstitial-ads-to-existing-app-with-admob-banner-ads-only

Answer (score 1):

Register your interstitial as a second Ad Unit using the Admob dashboard.